# Netbeans shows an error, but the code runs

Tags: java, netbeans

In one of my Java projects, in Netbeans, I have this "error". It doesn't affect my ability to compile and run my program, and I have no clue why it's there. I already asked some other people and it's baffling everyone.

I made a "minimal" example by removing some code (it *could* be more minimal, but this isn't code golf):

```
package cashregister;
public class CashRegister {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

But the red stop sign error persists:

[image: Seriously, WTF?]

I haven't run this minimal code version, but it should run. Obviously. I suspect this may be an issue with Netbeans. There are questions that run into a similar issue, but not in Java.

The hover text says:

```
cannot find symbol
     symbol: variable ImageIO
     location: class CashRegister

variable url may not have been initialized
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

Cannot find symbol indeed. This error started appearing when I copy and pasted in some code (found elsewhere on SO). I can link there if necessary. Note that the copied code actually used `ImageIO` and a variable named `url`.

---

Why is Netbeans showing an error here? How do I fix this?

Comment: @blahfunk I could try, but I've only been using for ~5 minutes before this happened.

Comment: Did you save the file? If so, try restarting netbeans

Comment: @dazito Running the program automatically saves it.

Comment: I can see no variable URL in your code. So the error can not come from this code

Comment: I would save all changes and run "Source -> Scan for external changes", which should refresh the workspace. Do you use the latest version of NetBeans? You can also report bugs within NetBeans (Help -> Report Issue).

Comment: @simdevmon It says `8.1` when I hover over the icon. I may report this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a "clean and build", but the error persisted.

I clicked the `x` and closed the file, and the error was gone when I opened it again. So problem solved (for now).

Closing Netbeans also solves the problem.

(I'm going to leave the question in case anyone else has a similar issue.)

I would assume that it was a cache issue. If anyone has a better explanation, feel free to post your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the cache solved the problem. The path of the cache directory is listed in the About window (menu Help/About). Close NetBeans, then delete (or rename) the directory. NetBeans will rebuild its cache when it starts up.

Comment: This helped me to solve a slightly different problem - the file was marked as "parse error", no restarts/reopen helped, navigator was not showing the class members. This started after reverting project from git. Cache deletion helped with evetything except navigator, still doesn't show anything